# BoxShadow is spreading over full screen width in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a `boxShadow` to a `Container` but the `BoxShadow` is spreading over full width of screen instead of width of `Sized Box`. For futher explanation `Container` is a child of a `SizedBox` and `SizedBox` is in `Column` the `crossAxisAlignment` of the `Column` is `stretch`. The code is given below.

```
class _AudioDetailsState extends State<AudioDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(heading: "Audio Player"),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue.shade50],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                ClipOval(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 125,
                        width: 125,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 5,
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                          )
                        ]),
                        child: const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                        )),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the current image of the output is given below

[image: Screenshot from genymotion emulator]

Comment: try wrapping the `Container` with `Align` widget so it won't fit the parent size

Comment: I did but it is not working. It is forming a square around the circle

Comment: well it's weird, I will tried out and give you an update.

Comment: Sorry My bad It worked

Comment: Please post your approach as answer @7mada

Comment: Thanks I will, give me a second to write it in a way that can help others in the future.

Comment: In your particular problem, if you assign `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` to your `Column` widget inside of `Container` it will take minimum space needed. But you should read this article about `Container` widget in order to better understand it's sizing behavior https://medium.com/jlouage/container-de5b0d3ad184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occur because of `crossAxisAlignment` value, using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` will stretches children across the cross axis.

the docs says "If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size might be ignored. Be specific when defining alignment."

To fix this you can either use other `crossAxisAlignment` value and provide the device width to the parent `Container`

```dart
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
  ClipOval(
  ...
```

Or warp the child with `Align`

```
 Align(
   child: ClipOval(
      child: SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            child: Container(
                height: 125,
                width: 125,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                     blurRadius: 5,
                     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                     spreadRadius: 5,
                   )
                   ]),
                 child: const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```